# Range.Validation method occure 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel, validation, error-handling

I use VBA to add validation to a cell wich depends from other cell where is another validation. Formula in all this validation has named ranges.
What I tried:

-place values in the cell which this validation depends;

-recalculate book after placing values

-i debug all code and there are no errors in it (error occur only in this code)

**Here is a code.**

```
Public Sub MakeValidation(ByVal ValidString As String, ByVal ValidAddress As String, ByVal ValidSheet As String, ByRef WB As Workbook)
    Dim n As Long
NewStart:
    Err.Clear
    n = n + 1
    If n = 10 Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo NewStart
    WB.Worksheets(ValidSheet).Range(ValidAddress).Validation.Delete
    Debug.Print "'" & Err.Number; "'" & "  " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo NewStart
    If CheckValidation(ValidAddress, ValidSheet, WB) = True Then
        WB.Worksheets(ValidSheet).Range(ValidAddress).Validation.Delete
    End If
    WB.Worksheets(ValidSheet).Range(ValidAddress).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                                                                 AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                                                 Operator:=xlBetween, _
                                                                 Formula1:=ValidString

End Sub
```

Have u any ideas why "On error goto NewStart" doesn't work?
And why when i run code by pressing "F5" it doesn't works but when i debug code it works?

Thank's a lot for your answer.
My english is not very good. Sorry for mistakes.

Comment: You'll need to use a `Resume` to avoid your error handler to crash, as it'll be handling the first error you encounter until it come accross a `Resume` statement. See answer in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

This `Resume` should be enough to avoid your issue (as explained in comments) :

```
Public Sub MakeValidation(ByVal ValidString As String, ByVal ValidAddress As String, ByVal ValidSheet As String, ByRef WB As Workbook)
    Dim n As Long
NewStart:
    Err.Clear
    n = n + 1
    If n = 10 Then Exit Sub
    Resume KeepRunning
KeepRunning:

    On Error GoTo NewStart

    WB.Worksheets(ValidSheet).Range(ValidAddress).Validation.Delete
    Debug.Print "'" & Err.Number; "'" & "  " & Err.Description
    If CheckValidation(ValidAddress, ValidSheet, WB) = True Then
        WB.Worksheets(ValidSheet).Range(ValidAddress).Validation.Delete
    End If
    WB.Worksheets(ValidSheet).Range(ValidAddress).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                                                                 AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                                                 Operator:=xlBetween, _
                                                                 Formula1:=ValidString
End Sub
```

I also get rid of the second `On Error GoTo NewStart` which was useless as you didn't "set off" the previous statement with `On Error GoTo 0`